# The negations of "for all"/"there exists": Are these results, axioms, or definitions?

Tags: logic

The negation of "For all x, P" is "There exists some x such that not-P."

The negation of "There exists some x such that P" is "For all x, not-P."

Are the above results, axioms, or definitions?

Comment: It depends on the logic system used... In some system, one of the quantifier is defined with the other one: e.g. $\exists = \lnot \forall \lnot$ (or vice versa). On other systems, they are both primitive notions.

Comment: In both cases, the above equivalences will be proved form axioms+rules+definitions.

Comment: It could be a definition of convenience for readability. You don't strictly require two different quantifiers. Technically, either would suffice.

Comment: It's not a logic definition per se, it just follows from what these words mean in English, which is what the formal symbols are based on. That if it is not the case that P holds for all x, then there is some x for which P is false, is just how the world works, and this nature of things is transferred in the formalization of these operators.